# Triac randomly triggers when there is noise in the supply

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, trigger

I am using BTA16-800CW (Snubberless version) to control AC appliances (LED lights) and it randomly turns on / flickers when I adjust the fan regulator in the same room (this may be creating some spikes in my mains).
I have already connected an MOV to my controller, however did not use snubber as the triac already have them inbuilt (http://www.st.com/en/thyristors-scr-and-ac-switches/standard-and-snubberless-triacs.html?querycriteria=productId=SC124)

The triac is driven by MOC3023 and it functions well otherwise.

Appreciate if you can guide me on any additional components required to avoid such random turn on.

Schematics
[image]

**Edit**
I suspect the MOC3023 causing the false trigger! Have anyone used other drivers for BTA16 (snubberless version) successfully without false triggers ?

**Update on 18-May-2018**
I have tried FOD4208 instead of MOC32023 and they did not stop the false trigger. Also if this is a duplicate question, then please help by giving the solution or the duplicate posts which has the solution.

**Update on 26-June-2018**
I tried another Triac with high dv/dt and the circuit works fine when the opto driver is removed (Keeping only the triac in the circuit). Also the tests shows that FOD4208 gives less false triggers than MOC3023 (FOD4208 seems to have high dv/dt).

Comment: Without a schematic how would you like me to guess?

Comment: I have not added the schematic initially assuming that the connections are standard while using a triac from AC control. I have anyway added the schematic now.

Comment: Triacs and SCRs are known to be vulnerable to fast spikes on their power input wiring. L+C filtering may stop that false triggering.

Comment: As per https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219686/triac-spurious-triggering-issue I suspect the MOC driver. However I am not sure about the alternatives to be used.

Comment: _"did not use snubber as the triac already have them inbuilt "_ - No, they don't. Snubberless triacs have characteristics that make them less likely to need a snubber. That doesn't mean they have one built-in. It also doesn't mean they're immune to noise and won't ever need a snubber.

Comment: @marcelm I assume that they have moderate immunity to noise as per their datasheet. Adding snubber again will not be feasible for my project.